# What is the arity of the following complex terms?

Tags: prolog, logic, arity

I understand that the two facts are expressed using complex terms which again have complex terms as arguments. There are three levels of terms nested inside terms.

`vertical(line(point(X,Y), point(X,Z))).`

`horizontal(line(point(X,Y), point(Z,Y))).`

Does this mean the overall complex term has an arity of one as the other complex terms are nested?

Comment: Arity of `vertical` and `horizontal` is 1. Arity of `line` is 2. Arity of `point` is 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that what you call "complex terms" are normally called *coumpound terms* in Prolog. You can easily check for the arity of Prolog terms yourself in the following way:

```
?- functor(vertical(line(point(X,Y), point(X,Z))), _, Arity).
Arity = 1.
```

As you can see, your intuition was correct in this particular case!

#### SWI7-specific

Since you have added the SWI-Prolog tag to your question, it may be useful to know that in SWI 7 there is also `compound_name_arity/3`, which works on compound terms of arity 0. (In other Prologs a compound term of arity zero would be an atom.) For example:

```
?- functor(f(), _, Arity).
ERROR: functor/3: Domain error: `compound_non_zero_arity' expected, found `f()'
?- compound_name_arity(f(), _, Arity).
Arity = 0.
```